# Ember broccoli plugin symlink exists error

Tags: windows, ember.js, symlink, file-exists, broccolijs

I am getting an error when running `ember s` in Windows, same project works on Linux.

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [object Object] failed with:
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, symlink 'C:\ClientUI\public\assets\chart' ->
 'C:\ClientUI\tmp\static_compiler-tmp_dest_dir-2LrrCtpg.tmp'
    at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:962:18)
    at FSMonitor._measure (C:\ClientUI\node_modules\heimdalljs-fs-monitor\index.
js:66:21)
    at Object.symlinkSync (C:\ClientUI\node_modules\heimdalljs-fs-monitor\index.
js:82:30)
    at symlinkWindows (C:\ClientUI\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:120:16)

    at symlinkOrCopySync (C:\ClientUI\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:63:5
)
    at StaticCompiler._copy (C:\ClientUI\node_modules\broccoli-static-compiler\i
ndex.js:59:3)
    at C:\ClientUI\node_modules\broccoli-static-compiler\index.js:25:12
    at tryCatch (C:\ClientUI\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:538:12)
    at invokeCallback (C:\ClientUI\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:553:13)
    at publish (C:\ClientUI\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:521:7)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
undefined
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: try after removing tmp folder  `rm -rf tmp`

Comment: Also are you running the command with administrator privileges?